# Djangocms on microsoft sql 2017

Tags: sql, django

Django Version: 1.11.10
Python Version: 3.6.4

I would install DjangoCms on mssql 2017 and I followed this steps

1. I installed djangocms with this setting

   > ```
   > DATABASES = { 
   >     'default': {
   >         'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
   >         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
   >         'HOST': 'localhost',
   >         'NAME': 'project.db',
   >         'PASSWORD': '',
   >         'PORT': '',
   >         'USER': ''
   >     }
   > }
   > ```
2. After verified the good connection with

   > python manage.py runserver

I modified the database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', #sql server
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'userdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'passworddb',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

And then I type:

```
>python manage.py migrate
>python manage.py runserver
>python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I can login as superuser but when I start with the cms_wizard I receive the following message:

**ProgrammingError at /it/cms_wizard/create/**

```
Exception Value:    
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'substr' is not a recognized built-in function name. (195) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. (156); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I have no idea how to solve the problem

Comment: The problem is most likely not with your database setup, but with the functions that the CMS runs behind the scenes when starting up. It tries running a `SUBSTR()` function, which isn't a valid SQL Server function, and thus fails.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu this could mean that DjangoCms is not compatible with sql server!

Comment: exactly. And is it? Does it say so on their website?

Comment: I don't know, it does not sound good for me